# Can we set up bookmarks in SE?

Tags: feature-request

Is there any way to set up bookmarks/reminders for myself in SE? Since some comments/questions/answers require a lot of work to resolve, I might not have time to deal with them immediately. But by checking on them I remove them from the list of notifications (top left SE dropdown menu, which has a red icon if there are unread things to deal with). So it means that when I get back again tomorrow, there won't be anything to remind me of these pending tasks. I had missed many things in this way, even my own questions occasionally, so I would love to have a feature which allows me to check any piece of text with a bookmark, which are then listed under my profile or inbox. Any idea how to make these things 'rememberable'? (Other than: "check your own questions regularly", "train your memory", "drink less"...)

Some workaround has already been suggested on the main SE meta site ([here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1569/181998) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2588/181998), thanks R.M), but I have some concerns about them:

- One cannot bookmark/favorite comments or answers directly.
- One cannot mark things simply as 'unread' (thanks Szabolcs).
- Upvoting an answer does not help to distinguish it, because I usually find multiple answers that are worth for upvoting.
- Favoriting a question (with many answers) does not help me to find out weeks later what did I actually like there: the question, an answer, or a comment?
- Browser bookmarks are not (necessarily) available from a different computer. I am aware of products dealing with such taskas, but I prefer domestic solutions.
- Browser bookmarks won't notify me if an answer was updated (like favoriting does with questions).
- I would like to get reminders/notifications from time to time about how many pending tasks I have. Note that such reminders would not notify me about changes in the answer (like favoriting does) but about the fact that I wanted to **do something** about that piece of text (like evaluating, or testing an answer, or simply replying to a comment).

Comment: You can mark them as favorites, but I agree that something like your bookmarks would come in handy.

Comment: Actually I have like 89 favorites, but never check them, and they don't really show up in any form that reminds me to deal with them.

Comment: [Here you go.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1569) In other words, use your own ways of bookmarking/set up reminders. [Also related](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2588). While they don't directly answer your question, it tells you their line of thinking

Comment: Thanks @R.M! I guess you are not surprised that I do not find any of the solutions provided there satisfactory (see my edit). Sad that there is not even an explanation why this feature was declined.

Comment: @IstvánZachar Re: the edit, some of those are actually doable. 1) Answers and comments both have direct links (see the "link" under the answer for the URL and the timestamp for comments for a permalink). 4) If you use Chrome, you can sync your bookmarks across machines & browsers using a Google account (use a throwaway account if you care about privacy, etc.) 2), 3) and 6) are, to some extent, manageable with extensions. 5) Is a problem and I see no other way other than periodically doing a diff of the answer source or automatically checking version number from the post revisions page

Comment: I'd also love to have something like "mark as unread" ...